# Spring session scope bean, thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, session, scope

I am building an application with Struts2, Spring, Hibernate.
Struts actions are managed by Spring, their scopes are "request" and I have session bean with some state for performing a conversation. Before I used Struts2 session map, but I wanted the "containsKey, put, get, cast" nightmare to dissapear. So I started using session scope bean managed by Spring.

Question: this bean isn't thread-safe? If we have multiple-windows-per-user-per-browser, we can get many threads in session bean? How to handle it? Build thread-safe session bean?

Comment: I recon you still will have a multithreading issue with multiple browsers, this can be averted by making your stuff synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Everything stored in a scope larger than request is potentially accessed by multiple threads, and must be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about "multiple-windows-per-user-per-browser" and also avoiding the "containsKey, put, get, cast" nightmare in Struts2, you could also look at the [struts2-conversation plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/).  The plugin would manage the thread-safety issues for you.